# How to add vertical text align in href in html?

Tags: html, href, text-align

Hai i have a list(dynamically i created the html),in that list i added many hyperlinks .Now i want to add that link in center how to do this?kindly help me

```
"<FONT SIZE=5;face=Droid Sans>"+"<p style=text-align:center>"+"<a  id='"+i+"'  href='#' >" +value +  "</a>"+"</p>"+"<hr style='border:1px solid #EBEBEB'/>"+"</FONT>"+ "</li>");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use embed of external style not inline style. I used `line-height` to make vertical align and `text-align: center` to center the text.

An example of adding vertical align to anchor:

```css
.anch{
    font-size:12px;
    color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="anch">Anchor</a>
```

Comment: i created the html dynamically .kindly guide me with inline style

Comment: Does the CSS property 'v-align:top;' exist? It's 'vertical-align: top' right?

Comment: ya i need the text  vertical align center

Comment: @user1324068, I update the link, but try to use css classes, it makes code more clear and easy to understand.

Comment: @PalAls the user1324068 is talking about 'vertical align' NOT horizontal align

Comment: line-height = height, and vertical-align=middle did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can give vertical text in href in **HTML** through easy css like this:-

```
  <a href="#" style="width:200px; height:100px; background:red; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; color:black;">shailender</a>
```

i hope this can be helpful for you.....

or see the demo:- http://jsbin.com/uwemuy/edit#html,live